# Meteor - select element options loading function always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using Autoform package in my Meteor project where I am trying to load the options of a select element dynamically as shown below. Even though the convertToObj function returns the select options correctly as tested in console.log below, the select box is not populated with the options options, can someone please tell me what I might be missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

```
      var convertToObj = function(arrayObj, callbackFn){
         var customerOptions = [];

         arrayObj.forEach(function(optionName){
            customerOptions.push( {label: optionName.name, value: optionName.value} );
         });

         callbackFn(customerOptions);
      }





      customerOpt:{
        type: String,
        label: "Customer Options",
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "select",
            options: function(){

                if (Meteor.isClient) {
                    var docId = '';
                    docId = AutoForm.getFieldValue('customer');
                    if(docId){           
                      var customerRecordCount = Customers.find({_id:docId, customerOptions:{$exists:true}}).count();
                      if( customerRecordCount > 0){
                          Customers.find({_id: docId}).map(function (c) {
                                  convertToObj(c.customerOptions, function(result){
                                      console.log(result); //Prints OK!
                                      return result;
                                  });
                          });
                      }else{
                        return {};
                      }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but from my point of view you are calling the convertToObj with an Async callback. So you do not return anything (undefined) in case of `if (docId)` and `customerRecordCount > 0`.

The statement of `return result` is NOT the result for your `options: function()` block.

For a first debugging test, just `return { valid values }` and see that the select box is filled quite right.

---

Update:

You should return a valid array like:

```
options: [
      {label: "hello", value: 123},
      {label: "world!", value: "world"}
]
```

or

```
options: function() { 
  return [
      {label: "hello", value: 123},
      {label: "world!", value: "world"}
  ]
}
```

---

Update 2:

```
var selectOptions = []
var customerRecord = Customers.findOne({_id:docId})
if (customerRecord) {
  _.each(customerRecord.customerOptions, function(opt) {
    selectOptions.push({label: opt.name, value: opt.value});
  })
}
return selectOptions;
```

Comment: You are correct when I changed return result to return {label: "test", value: 1}; I still get nothing in the select box options...any thoughts what I might be missing / how to return the values generated to the select box? Thanks

Comment: Hi, please read my update section. I guess you still return not the right values. Should be an array.

Comment: Thanks, if I return plain array object as mentioned in your updated answer, everything works smoothly but if I use the code:

                      return Customers.find({_id: docId}).map(function (c) {
convertToObj(c.customerOptions, function(result){
                                      console.log(result); //Prints OK!
                                      return result;
                                  });                      });
it will always showing error. Not sure what could be wrong with the .map call? Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: As I said, the `.map()` will make Async Calls so you do not get a result out from that while inside this function. I couldn't identify your data layout. Are the options stored in ONE document you try to locate or do you find a NUMBER of documents you want to add to the options?

Comment: I am trying to grab the data from one document based on its _id, the document structure (schema) is as simple as {
   name: test,
   customerOptions: [{name: test1}, {name: test2}]
}
customerOptions is an array of objects as shown above. What I am trying to do is to take the customerOptions array convert it to the select options objects array with label, value so that they can be displayed as select options...makes sense? Thanks

Comment: I managed to make it load the select options correctly but the problem is that the code run async, so if .map was delayed for any reason (network traffic, db size...etc) I will get nothing loaded in select....any thought how I can ensure that return result wait for .map to return? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. I guess if you are just looking for one possible record, just look for one and use that resulting document to iterate its options.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. I guess if you are just looking for one possible record, just look for one and use that resulting document to iterate its options.

Comment: Thanks Tom, your updated code works perfectly, the only problem I can expect in this code is that if findOne took more time than expected (ex. due to network / net slow connection, the function will return undefined since code is async...any thoughts how I can make sure code in _.each won't execute before findOne returns its results? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, no, `findOne()` will always return with the defined document or as undefined. It is not ~async~ like map. So you should get the right output. The only important thing is that you have to wait on start for the readyness of your subscription. But once you have data in your form everything should work as expected.

Comment: Just to make sure I got the concept of findOne being sync right regarding fine one, so if I have in line #1 >> findOne() call then in line #2 >> console.log('test') line 2 will never be executed before line 1 is correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as we used that it works like you described.